# Why I can't get property values, set in one class to another class in c#/xaml metro app?

Tags: c#, oop, properties, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I was developing an app in WinRT, I had requirement of passing property values, which are set in one class, to another class, but I am not able to get them. My below code will explain you my problem. Please note I have tested this in simulator and added the capability for location in manifest. I have [set location](http://michaelcrump.net/a-few-additional-options-inside-the-windows-simulator-in-vs11-beta) in simulator.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass();
    MyTextBlock.Text = objMyClass.Lat.ToString() + ", " + objMyClass.Long.ToString();
}
```

MyClass.cs

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        FindLatLong();
    }

    public async void FindLatLong()
    {
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        var pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Lat = pos.Coordinate.Latitude;
        Long = pos.Coordinate.Longitude;
    }
}
```

I am getting output "0,0"

Comment: Did you expect to get something different?

Comment: yes, as I have manually set the co-ordinates in simulator, http://michaelcrump.net/a-few-additional-options-inside-the-windows-simulator-in-vs11-beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/fdecdee9-e019-4f81-bed9-5192145015bc/) from MSDN forum.

Answer (score 2):

FindLatLong is executed asynchronously, therefore Lat / Lon properties are are not set directly after the constructor

Comment: Execute it synchronously or add an event that is called when the coordinates have been set

Answer (score 0):

Another way of showing your location would be to implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface and bind your textbox to the properties of the class.